# How to paste a formula via Macro in cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to paste a formula in Excel cell via VBA but with no luck.
When i try this code it perfectly works -

`ActiveSheet.Range("B7").Value = "=VLOOKUP(A7,$A$1:$B$3,2,0)"`

But when i try this code

`ActiveSheet.Range("B7").Value = "=VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(LOOKUP(2,1/($A$5:A7<>""),$A$5:A7),Instructions!$A$4:$B$40,2,0),NTFS!XFC7-2),'Trial Balance'!$I$55:$J$1048576,2,0)"`

it ends up with an Error 1004 Run time error - Application defined or Object defined error.

I just want the formula to be pasted into the cell any other code would work. Please help me with the reason why this error occurs, and also request you to come up with a crack or an alternative to paste the formula.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Change the `""` to be `""""`

Comment: Where exactly, there are so many times i've used them? @YowE3K

Comment: There is only one `""` in that formula - the section saying `$A$5:A7<>""`

Comment: Don't change the `"` outside the string, just change the `""` inside the string to be `""""`.

Comment: OMGGGGG!!! Thanks a lot man! @YowE3K

Comment: the term is `assign`,  it is not `paste`

Comment: @jsotola -- I think the word `paste` is probably intentional.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B7").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(LOOKUP(2,1/($A$5:A7<>""""),$A$5:A7),Instructions!$A$4:$B$40,2,0),NTFS!XFC7-2),'Trial Balance'!$I$55:$J$1048576,2,0)"
```

Note that value was replaced with formula and the quotes after <> were doubled.

Comment: Thanks Man. It works!

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B7").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(LOOKUP(2,1/($A$5:A7<>""),$A$5:A7),Instructions!$A$4:$B$40,2,0),NTFS!XFC7-2),'Trial Balance'!$I$55:$J$1048576,2,0)"
```

Comment: You need quadruple quotes in the middle `A7<>""""`

Comment: FormulaR1C1 is used with a rare type of cell referencing, like this: Range("D4").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C[-2]*10"

Comment: Thanks Man! This thing works!

Comment: @AnkushSurana Actually, this answer suffers from the same problem as your original code.  (The string becomes `=VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(LOOKUP(2,1/($A$5:A7<>"),$A$5:A7),Instructions!$A$4:$B$40,2,0),NTFS!XFC7-2),'Trial Balance'!$I$55:$J$1048576,2,0)`, which is not a valid formula.)  I'm surprised you marked it as the accepted answer.